# Liferay 7.3.5GA6 custom index search and ddmFieldArray

Tags: java, elasticsearch, liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I'm trying to develop a custom web content search portlet for Liferay 7.3.5 GA6, using SearchContext, IndexSearcherHelperUtil and all the other stuff.

I have some DDMStructure with different fields and, from what I've seen on the elasticsearch index, this fields are indexed in a nested document, like this:

```
"ddmFieldArray": [
{
"ddmFieldName": "ddm__text__37702__nome_it_IT",
"ddmValueFieldName": "ddmFieldValueText_it_IT",
"ddmFieldValueText_it_IT": "Nome esempio",
"ddmFieldValueText_it_IT_String_sortable": "nome esempio"
}
,
{
"ddmFieldName": "ddm__text__37702__descrizione_breve_it_IT",
"ddmValueFieldName": "ddmFieldValueText_it_IT",
"ddmFieldValueText_it_IT": "Esempio di descrizione breve da indicizzare",
"ddmFieldValueText_it_IT_String_sortable": "esempio di descrizione breve da indicizzare"
}
]
```

which is different from the old way I used to know, where the custom fields were indexed like `ddm__[keyword/text]__[structure_id]__[field_name]`

Now, I understand this different way of indexing is due to an improvement to avoid elastic issues (Limit of total fields has been exceeded) but...After executing the search, there is no **ddmFieldArray** in the *com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document .getFields*, so I'm unable to get the ddmstructure fields values from the elastic search index.

Here's the code:

```
long journalArticleClassId = ClassNameLocalServiceUtil.getClassNameId(JournalArticle.class.getName());

SearchContext searchContext = new SearchContext();
searchContext.setClassTypeIds(new long[] {journalArticleClassId});
searchContext.setCompanyId(companyId);
searchContext.setStart(QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
searchContext.setEnd(QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
        
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQueryImpl();
            
        
MatchQuery approvedQuery = new MatchQuery(Field.STATUS, String.valueOf(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED));

query.add(approvedQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());


Hits resultHits = IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search(searchContext, query);

for (Document doc: resultHits.getDocs()) {          
    doc.getFields().forEach((k, v) -> _log.debug(k)); //No ddm structure field
}
```

Is this still an improvement or just an unexpected behaviour?

Any way to solve or extend this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "ddmFieldArray" field is a nested field that it is not returned by default.
You have to fetch it from the document source field that is stored in an internal "_source" field in Elasticsearch (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/search-fields.html )

In order to do this in Liferay, you have to use some search methods that aren't available in the old **portal-kernel** search classes, you have to use the new search classes that are available in the **portal-search-api** module that is located in *modules/apps/portal-search*

These are the changes you have to apply to your code:

- Before executing the search, you have to add the "fetchSource" flag to your search adding this code:

```
    searchRequestBuilderFactory.builder(
        searchContext
    ).fetchSource(
        true
    ).build();
```

- After executing the search, you have to get the Document objects from the SearchResponse object. This SearchResponse is available in the searchContext using this code:

```
    /* Execute search */
    IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search(searchContext, query);
    
    /* Get results from search response */
    SearchResponse searchResponse = searchContext.getAttribute("search.response");
    List<SearchHit> resultHits = searchResponse.getSearchHits().getSearchHits();
    
    /* Iterate */
    for (SearchHit searchHit : resultHits)  {
        Document doc = searchHit.getDocument();
    
        ...your stuff...
    }
```

You have some examples about fetching source and gettings SearchResponse in following Liferay classes:

- [com.liferay.document.library.search.test.DLSearchFixture](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/02396f764ad152bde79f062c7cb1ca941a670234/modules/apps/document-library/document-library-test/src/testIntegration/java/com/liferay/document/library/search/test/DLSearchFixture.java#L73-L92), see method searchOnlyOneSearchHit where fetchSource(true) is setted and the SearchResponse object is got from the searchContext
- [com.liferay.account.internal.retriever.AccountOrganizationRetrieverImpl](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/02396f764ad152bde79f062c7cb1ca941a670234/modules/apps/account/account-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/account/internal/retriever/AccountOrganizationRetrieverImpl.java#L56-L75) where some searchs are done using SearchRequest and SearchResponse.
- [com.liferay.asset.internal.util.AssetHelperImpl](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/02396f764ad152bde79f062c7cb1ca941a670234/modules/apps/asset/asset-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/asset/internal/util/AssetHelperImpl.java#L562-L566) where searchRequestBuilderFactory is used.

I have also implemented a groovy script example that you can execute it from: **Control Panel => Server Administration => Script**

- **Code for 7.3.x version:**

```
import com.liferay.registry.*;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.*;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.generic.*;
import com.liferay.portal.search.legacy.searcher.SearchRequestBuilderFactory;
import com.liferay.portal.search.searcher.SearchResponse;
import com.liferay.portal.search.hits.SearchHit;
import com.liferay.portal.search.document.Document;

/* Get SearchRequestBuilderFactory reference using RegistryUtil, because we cannot use "@Reference" in a groovy script */
Registry registry = RegistryUtil.getRegistry();
SearchRequestBuilderFactory searchRequestBuilderFactory = registry.getService(registry.getServiceReference(SearchRequestBuilderFactory.class.getName()));

/* Create SearchContext */
SearchContext searchContext = new SearchContext();
searchContext.setCompanyId(com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalUtil.getCompany(actionRequest).getCompanyId());
searchContext.setStart(-1);
searchContext.setEnd(-1);

/* Line to fetch stored source of documents */
searchRequestBuilderFactory.builder(
    searchContext
).fetchSource(
    true
).build();

/* Get journal articles that are approved (status = 0) */
MatchQuery approvedQuery = new MatchQuery(Field.STATUS, String.valueOf(0));
MatchQuery journalArticleQuery = new MatchQuery("entryClassName", com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle.class.getName());

BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQueryImpl();
query.add(approvedQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());
query.add(journalArticleQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());

/* Execute search */
IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search(searchContext, query);

/* Get results from search response */
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchContext.getAttribute("search.response");
List<SearchHit> resultHits = searchResponse.getSearchHits().getSearchHits();

/* Iterate */
for (SearchHit searchHit : resultHits)  {
    Document doc = searchHit.getDocument();
    out.println("entryClassPK: " + doc.getValue("entryClassPK"));
    out.println("ddmFieldArray: " + doc.getValues("ddmFieldArray"));
    out.println("");
}
```

- **Code for 7.4.x version:**

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.*;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.generic.*;
import com.liferay.portal.search.legacy.searcher.SearchRequestBuilderFactory;
import com.liferay.portal.search.searcher.SearchResponse;
import com.liferay.portal.search.hits.SearchHit;
import com.liferay.portal.search.document.Document;

import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.module.util.SystemBundleUtil;

/* Get SearchRequestBuilderFactory reference using the BundleContext, because we cannot use "@Reference" in a groovy script */
BundleContext bundleContext = SystemBundleUtil.getBundleContext();
SearchRequestBuilderFactory searchRequestBuilderFactory = bundleContext.getService(bundleContext.getServiceReferences(SearchRequestBuilderFactory.class.getName(), null)[0]);

/* Create SearchContext */
SearchContext searchContext = new SearchContext();
searchContext.setCompanyId(com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalUtil.getCompany(actionRequest).getCompanyId());
searchContext.setStart(-1);
searchContext.setEnd(-1);

/* Line to fetch stored source of documents */
searchRequestBuilderFactory.builder(
    searchContext
).fetchSource(
    true
).build();

/* Get journal articles that are approved (status = 0) */
MatchQuery approvedQuery = new MatchQuery(Field.STATUS, String.valueOf(0));
MatchQuery journalArticleQuery = new MatchQuery("entryClassName", com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle.class.getName());

BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQueryImpl();
query.add(approvedQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());
query.add(journalArticleQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST.getName());

/* Execute search */
IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search(searchContext, query);

/* Get results from search response */
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchContext.getAttribute("search.response");
List<SearchHit> resultHits = searchResponse.getSearchHits().getSearchHits();

/* Iterate */
for (SearchHit searchHit : resultHits)  {
    Document doc = searchHit.getDocument();
    out.println("entryClassPK: " + doc.getValue("entryClassPK"));
    out.println("ddmFieldArray: " + doc.getValues("ddmFieldArray"));
    out.println("");
}
```

In your code you should replace the RegistryUtil or BundleContext usage with the "@Reference" annotation.

Let me know if you have any problem with my example.

Comment: Thank you so much @jorgediaz-lr , your solution is working perfectly and your answer was awesome.
I have a problem just with the RegistryUtili and the @ Reference: deployed with this code, the service had some problem with some unsatisfied reference (to the registry or the registryutil) so, for now,I'll leave it without any reference.

Thank you again!